# Translating Gollum's "Go away and never come back!"

Tags: imperative

One of the more memorable scenes in the Lord of the Ring's movies is the moment when Gollum's two personalities argue with each other, and finally one of his selves orders the other, "Go away and never come back!" So, let's say we are rendering this in Latin. At first I thought it would be this:

> Discede et numquam redi!

1. However, after thinking about it, even though we say "never come back" in the present tense in English, the returning action would actually be in the future, so should the imperative be the future imperative?

> Discede et numquam redito!

In other words, in Latin should it be "Go away and never *will* you come back!"

2. Also, I wonder if *discede* is the right idiom. Would it be stronger and more appropriate to write:

> Abi et numquam redito!

Comment: Can you explain 'E ut ab' in the last version? You appear to be using 2 prepositions, but without supplying nouns to serve as their objects.

Comment: @cnread I think it is an idiom that roughly means "away from". So, "e ut ab" would be "go away!"

Comment: Can you cite a source? I've never seen that as an idiom, and a corpus search on PHI didn't yield any results. Is it Medieval or otherwise non-Classical?

Comment: Tyler Durden: In Latin the present & future tenses are not separate countries; see A & G section 468.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"et numquam" should be avoided (North and Hillard, Latin Prose Composition p. 11, note; Rubenbauer-Hoffmann, Lateinische Grammatik §224a)

Abi neque umquam redi

Comment: Welcome to this site.  interesting input from N&H. FWIW, **(1)** PHI has more [*et numquam*](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23et+numquam) than [*neque umquam*](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=neque+umquam); **(2)** Not particular to this answer but virtually to every suggestion in this page: It is not so clear that *numquam* can be used with imperative as in English. Still waiting for a classical example. A question [was asked](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/can-we-use-numquam-with-a-imperative) here about this.

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right: "et numquam" does exist. I am trying to figure what N&H had in mind. Rubenbauer-Hoffmann §224a has a parallel example: "Neque" is used to bind sentences together; "et non" is ONLY used when a single word or entity of words is negated (or so they say). I think this might be true for "et numquam", which is perhaps more often used to combine words than sentences. PHI gives three instances in Cicero for ”et numquam” (words negated, not sentences), thirteen for ”neque umquam”.
But the important thing is ”numquam / ne umquam” + imperative. I’ll look out for that.

Comment: What a delightful forum! Enlightened by  d_e above (thanks) and the discussion here about the problems of ”numquam” + imperative I now suggest:
Abi nec umquam redieris !

Answer (score 4):

*Abi* is good and regularly used in this context, often with *hinc* added, e.g.,

- Abi hinc - *Go away*
- Abi hinc ab oculis (or: ... e conspectu meo) - *Get out of my sight*
- Abi hinc in malam rem - literally: *Go away to misfortune*, probably better translated as "jump in a lake" etc.

Then there is the useful interjection *apage*, translated by Lewis & Short as: *away with thee! away! begone! avaunt!* --- and often used in the form *apage te* (*a me*). *Amove te* is another option.

With that in mind, I think your suggestion: *Abi et numquam redito* is pretty good already, and may be seasoned to taste by adding a little *hinc, apage*, etc.

(Like cnread in the comments, I cannot make heads and tails of *e ut ab*.)

Answer (score 3):

You've done a great job, just avoid the future imperative.

1. In general, never use the "future imperative." Unless you are in a courtroom. The term "**future** imperative" is not accurate.  It should have been named the "**formal** imperative," since it has nothing to do with future time. (If someone wants to open this can of worms, please create a new question.)
2. *discede* and *abi* are both great to use here. They are very common and the Lewis&Short lexicon says they are both used

> frequently in all periods and sorts of composition

Specifically, *discedere* can apply to people

> *To depart from* any place **or person**, *to go away from, to leave*

While *abeo* has a specific usage appropriate to Gollum's situation. But, This sense is only used in poetry (Terence, Plautus)

> The *imper*. "abi" is often a simple exclamation or address, either with a friendly or reproachful signif.

In conclusion, keep *discede / abi et numquam redi*. Gollum is not a fancy hobbit, not even as Smeagol. His word choice should reflect his character. No courtroom expressions, and no need for local idioms or purpose clauses with *ut.* He's just saying GTFO!

Note - I translated a couple of Gollum/Bilbo's riddles from the Hobbit into (simplish) Latin and posted them in my bio/about me page.

Comment: "This sense is only used in poetry (Terence, Plautus)" -- these two gentlemen weren't poets but playwrights, and between them are our best source of colloquial everyday Latin. It's also not true, cf. "Abi hinc cum tribunatibus ac rogationibus tuis" (Livius, [Ab urbe condita 6,40](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.6.shtml#40)).

Comment: I agree that they have a lot of colloq. Latin. But I'm not saying that "abi hinc" is only in Terence/Plautus, I'm saying that only they use it in the sense of "friendly or reproachful signif." (http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=abi&la=la) (Also, plays = poetry. Latin comedy is written in iambic senarius & iambic trimeter mostly).

Comment: @eyesplice17 I think that entry is referring to a pretty specific usage of *abi* similar to English "get out of here!" The literal usage ("go away") is common to all authors and can certainly be friendly/reproachful as the context dictates, cf. https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23abi%23&first=111

Answer (score 0):

There's imperative, "peri" (from "pereo-"to die) giving, "Go and die!". If the receiver goes away and dies, he won't be coming back.