# Can we use "numquam" with a imperative?

Tags: classical-latin, imperative

In English(in Portuguese, as well) we can use the adverb "nunquam" with an imperative "Never do/say/etc something!
I'm asking because when I read the dictionaries, I never see a sentence with "nunquam" and a imperative.
I googled, and I didn't find anything abou it.
Has ever any author used it with an imperative?

Comment: My immediate reaction is that ne+subjunctive or noli+infinitive would be used to form a negative command (prohibition), and then umquam would be used; but I haven't confirmed this.

Comment: My intuition, similarly, is that you could use numquam with a subjunctive or noli + umquam, but not numquam with an imperative; I'll need to find some actual confirmation before making this an answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

(*) As suggested in the comments we can have negative command with *numquam* + perfect subjective.

> quod [vulnus] is [Pomponio] se passum pro Caesare pugnantem gloriabatur, **‘numquam fugiens respexeris’** inquit (Quint.Inst.6.3.75.3)

As for using numquam +  imperative this is still to be determined.

---

(*) **Edit:** Some texts read this with a question mark. i.e., "Would you have never looked back when fleeing?”" (See Loeb translation of the same referred text in "Fragmentary Republican Latin": "as C. Caesar said to Pomponius, displaying a wound on his face received in Sulpicius’ [P. Sulpicius Rufus ] insurrection [88 BC], because he boasted of having suffered it while fighting for Caesar: “Would you have never looked back when fleeing?")

But Loeb original translation of Quintilian reads as command: "... as in the riposte of Gaius Caesar to Pomponius, who had exhibited a wound on his face received in Sulpicius’ insurrection and boasted of having suffered it while fighting for Caesar: “Never look round when you are running away”";

I think by context the two readings are possible (this statement of this C. Caesar was an example to the orator how a comment can pop someone's boast.)